# How do I make certain apps appear in the Recent Apps section in the dock, and others not appear?

Tags: applications, google-chrome, dock

There's some apps I would like to disappear from the dock in the recent apps, others I want to stay.

[image: I want the Chrome Reddit PWA to stay in the dock recent apps, but, for example, I would like CleanMyMac to disappear once closed.]

The current behaviour is that when the recent apps are full, Reddit disappears instead of staying in the recent apps.

I want the Chrome Reddit PWA to stay in the dock recent apps, but, for example, I would like CleanMyMac to disappear once closed. How do I configure this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you want an app to stay, move it out of the recents section.

The recents section will not hold more than 3 apps at once, but if you have more than 3 apps open then it will grow to accommodate the open apps. So, if you close Reddit PWA then you now only have 3 apps and Clean My Mac will stay even when closed.